# Make the denominator rational

Tags: roots, rationalising-denominator

I am doing the homework of a recorded video in a course, and I came across this question which I am not able to solve:

Simplify the denominator:
$\dfrac{12}{3+\sqrt5-2\sqrt2}$

And I am not able to understand the solution:

[image: 2]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution has a typo in line 2: it should be $\sqrt5$, not $\sqrt2$ in the denominator there.

Comment: @Arthur Is there an age restriction at mathSE?

Comment: @user2661923  I am in class 5.

Comment: Manipulating radicals is way beyond class 5 (in India this means students of age 10). At least it was the case when I was in class 5 (around 1990).

Comment: Oh sorry, It was a typo. I am actually in class 6. I know that there are no radicals in class 6, but I am preparing for prmo, which I will give in class 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we are doing is a process called "rationalizing" the denominator. The process relies on the property that

$$( a + b)\cdot ( a -  b) = a^2 - b^2 $$

So when you have a fraction as follows

$$F = \frac{12}{3+\sqrt5 - 2\sqrt2}$$

Let $a = 3+\sqrt5$, $b = 2\sqrt2$

$$F = \frac{12}{a-b}$$

Now multiplying numerator and denominator by $a+b$, we have

$$F = \frac{12(a+b)}{(a-b)(a+b)} = \frac{12(3+\sqrt5 + 2\sqrt2)}{(3+\sqrt5)^2-(2\sqrt2)^2} = \frac{12(3+\sqrt5+2\sqrt2)}{6(1+\sqrt5) }$$

$$\implies F =\frac{2(3+\sqrt5+2\sqrt2)}{1+\sqrt5} $$

Now you can repeat the process to simplify it further

Comment: :-) Thanks @Dhanvi Sreenivasan